# Is there a way to generate new HTML elements from an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I working on an Electron app, it uses the Reddit API (snoowarp module) to get posts from my subreddit as an object.

In my **index.html** I have a div element to show these posts, now I'm looking for a way to generate them as **HTML div elements** then putting them there.

This is a picture of my app:

[image: This is a picture of my app]

and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my solution for your problem. I hope it will help you :)

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.textContent = "Hello";
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "red");
container.appendChild(newDiv);
```

```css
#red{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Well this is a simple way to create an element then putting it on anther one, you're using classes, can you do it again using IDs?
Now the rest is creating a function to generate this from an object.